# PHP post- increment/descrement operator precedence

Tags: php, operator-precedence

In documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php it is said, that `++` and `--` operators have very high precedence.
But as i know, `++$x` and `$x++` is not the same. Moreover, `$x++` should have minimal precedence, because it is calculated after everything is done:

```
$x = 1;
var_dump(1 and $x--); // and operator is one of last operators in the table, it will be executed before post decrement
```

So, post- increment/decrement operators should be in this table in the bottom?

Comment: This is why I never write such a code in any language, no matter how compact it is :)

Comment: @zoltan-tamasi I am going to make ZCE exam, so i need to know that. In real life normal person would never do that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If the operators are placed before the variable then the variable is changed before any other order of operations.

```
$a=4;
$x=++$a + 6; will result in $x=11 and $a=5
$x=$a++ + 6; will result in $x=10 and $a=5
```

When the operators are in front it takes precedence over all other operators. 
You can find a simple explanation at the following site as well:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php